# How to reference a cell in VBA using values in another cell

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I need to copy a range of data from another sheet that contains the month of the data that is in say cell A1. So I have Feb 2017 in cell A1 and a row of data in another sheet from 1 Jan 2017 to 31 Dec 2017 with the dates is row A and the data in the rows below. I want to create a macro that whenever I run it, it will read cell A1 and if it is Feb 2017, it will copy the columns of data from 1 Feb 2017 to 28 Feb 2017 and if the cell A1 is March 2017, it will copy from 1 March 2017 to 31 March 2017. How can i do that?

I recorded the macro but the cell referenced is locked so it will always copy from 1 Feb 2017 to 28 Feb 2017 which is not I wanted.

```
Windows("MASTERFILE.xlsm").Activate
Range("FA2:FT2").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("NEW_FILE.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("borrowing").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("MASTERFILE.xlsm").Activate
Range("FA25:FT28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("NEW_FILE.xlsm").Activate
Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Main Page").Select
```

End Sub

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
Sub GetDataByMonth()
    Dim mth As Integer, year As Integer, data As Range, item As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        mth = VBA.DatePart("m", .Range("A1"))
        year = VBA.DatePart("yyyy", .Range("A1"))
    End With

    Set data = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A200")

    For Each item In data
        If VBA.DatePart("m", item) = mth And VBA.DatePart("yyyy", item) = year Then
            Range(Cells(Item.Row, 2), Cells(Item.Row, 40)).Copy
            Item.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next item
End Sub
```

- Assumes your dates are formatted as dates in the s/sheet
- It copies each line at a time.
- Assumes the data you want to copy in column B (2) to AN (40)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! It worked but how do i make it such that it only copies from B onwards instead of the whole row?

Comment: Do you know exactly the width of the row? For example, will it always be from B to H?

Comment: Suppose you want to copy the row from col B to H. Update the `item.EntireRow.Copy` to `Range(Cells(item.Row, 2), Cells(item.Row, 8)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & rw)`

Comment: I wanted to copy the row from col B to AN and paste the values in the same row. So i did something like this but it didnt work:      
    Range(Cells(item.Row, 2), Cells(item.Row, 40)).EntireRow.Copy
           Range(Cells(item.Row, 2), Cells(item.Row,40)).EntireRow. PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
           :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: Where do you want to copy the cells? Separate sheet but same row?

Comment: Same sheet, same tab, same row. I am trying to copy the values and paste it over the formulas so that the row contains value instead of formulas

Comment: Hi Alex P, the code managed to copy and the paste the cells at the correct place, but the figures were wrong. What could be the problem?

Comment: Wrong how? Format or actual value is wrong (e.g. was 10 but now 20)?

Comment: The format and values are both wrong. After i hit the macro, E17 was a blank well at first but now it has the value 0 and P17 to AN17 all became blank